# Regex matching multiple negative lookaheads

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to match a string (using a Perl regex) only if it doesn't start with "abc:" or "defg:", but I can't seem to find out how. I've tried something like

```
^(?:(?!abc:)|(?!defg:))
```

Comment: that asks for any string that doesn't start abc: *or* doesn't start defg:, which is any string

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Lookahead `(?=foo)`, `(?!foo)` and lookbehind `(?<=foo)`, `(?<!foo)` do not consume any characters.

You can do multiple assertions:

```
^(?!abc:)(?!defg:)
```

or:

```
^(?!defg:)(?!abc:)
```

...and the order does not make a difference.

---

You can use [De Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) (as other answers do):

```
(NOT A) AND (NOT B) <=> NOT (A OR B)
```

...and shorten the expression to:

```
^(?!abc:|defg:)
```

Answer (score 9):

Try doing this:

```
^(?!(?:abc|defg):)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex:

`^(?!abc:|defg:)\s*\w+`

This will avoid line start with **"abc:"** and **"defg:"** as you want.

Answer (score 1):

… or we could have dropped the alternation from the original expression:

```
^(?:(?!abc:)(?!defg:))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:(?!abc:|defg:).)*$
```

Try this. See the demo at *http://regex101.com/r/hQ9xT1/18*.

Comment: The preceding `\b` are redundant, and OP doesn't say anything about whatever that follows.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the task:

```
^(?!(defg|abc):).*
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;

while(<DATA>)
{
    my $line=$_;
    print $line unless($line=~m/^(abc|defg*)/m);
}

__DATA__
ebc this is testing ebc
dbc this is testing dbc
defg this is testing defg
abc this is testing abc
defg this is testing defg
```